# Representation theory for symmetries of probability distribution functions

Tags: pr.probability, rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, probability-distributions, information-geometry

I would like to parameterize all the possible modifications to a probability density function. Is there a representation theory for this? Something along the lines of, these are all the operators $L$ that act on a pdf $f(x)$ such that $(1 + \epsilon L)f$ (for small $\epsilon$) is positive everywhere and still integrates to $1$.

I guess it must be some kind of infinite-dimensional symmetry group but hopefully there's a relatively convenient way to parameterize such transformations.

I asked on math.stackexchange but thought maybe mathoverflow might be more suitable.